# Change the message in bar with no results after initcomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using Datables and I need to set a message when the Datatable is being created. Also when it finishes I need it to change. I've got this so far. Any idea how I can make it work?

```js
var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": false,
  "stateSave": true,
  "aaSorting": [],
  "deferRender": true,
  "ajax": {
    url: Link,
    data: {
      OpenDocs: '1'
    },
    type: "post"
  },
  language: {
    "zeroRecords": " "
  },
  "initComplete": function(settings, json) {

    language: {
      "zeroRecords": " No data here. "
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this attribute it will work:

```
 oLanguage: {
         "sProcessing" : "Custom message while processing",
         "sEmptyTable" : "My Custom Message On Empty Table"
  }
```